# suppress events for Flex objects

Tags: apache-flex, events, actionscript, flex3

[Edit]
The main question here loosely translates as 'is Flex multi-threaded'? I have since found out that it is not, so I won't have data mysteriously changing half way through an operation. The code below worked, but made things awkward and confusing. I eventually fixed the problem with an architecture change, eliminating the need to suppress events. As the first commenter suggested.

Infinite loops were eliminated by changing the way events were listened to and performing certain actions explicitly rather than via events.

Collating events was made easier using a command pattern.

Basically, do not use the code below if you come across this page!
[/Edit]

I'm building some Flex applications using a simple, lightweight MVC pattern. Models extend or encapsulate a dispatcher and fire events when updated. I'm stuck with Flex 3.5.

In some situations, I'll want to suppress these events to avoid infinite loops or help collate multiple actions into a single event.

My first stab at a solution that doesn't litter the models with unnecessary and confusing code is this:

```
    private var _suppressEvents:Boolean = false;
    public function suppressEvents(callback:Function):void
    {
        // In case of error, ensure the suppression is turned off, then re-throw
        var err:Error = null;
        _suppressEvents = true;
        try 
        {
            callback();
        }
        catch(e:Error)
        {
            err = e;
        }
        _suppressEvents = false;
        if (err)
        {
            throw (err);
        }
    }

    public function dispatch(type:String, data:*):void
    {
        // Suppress if called from a suppress callback.
        if (!_suppressEvents)
        {

            _dispatcher.dispatchEvent(new DataEvent(type, data));
        }
    }
```

Obviously I call 'suppressEvents' with a function containing the model code I wish to run.

My questions:

1: Is there a chance I could accidentally lose events using this technique?

2: Do I need to think about any other error edge cases when it comes to ensuring I don't accidentally end up in a suppressed state after a call?

3: Is there a cleaner way I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: My intuition is that if you're code is written in such a way that event dispatching can cause infinite loops there is a problem w/ your business logic.  I think you're trying to solve a problem that you shouldn't be having.  But, it's hard to tell from the little information we have.

Comment: The problem extends further than that described here. I'm also interfacing with an external system that allows synchronisation of application instances across the web. The problem there is that when the models are updated by the sync system they fire an event, which is fired across the sync system. Another instance would then do the same action, firing the message back, etc. I'm attempting a solution much the same as this. If you can propose a better pattern to overcome the problem, I would love to hear it.

Comment: The other problem is event aggregation. If I'm iterating through a list applying an operation, that operation may fire an event each time. Each event costs time and bandwidth, so I would prefer to suppress the individual events and send one event relating to the overall operation. I can either use a system to allow the events to be suppressed or I can write new functions to perform the operations in an eventless way. The proliferation of functions that result seem over the top, messy and problematic to me. I want to know if I'm translating between frying pan and fire doing it this way...

Comment: But yes, in general I can understand your attitude to possible infinite loops in event code...

Comment: When you say you are iterating through a list what does that mean?  Is that a custom class you've created?  Or did you mean Array or ArrayCollection or Vector?  One normally wouldn't iterate through a Flex List class [although they may iterate over it's dataProvider]

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm using 'list' in a general sense. The underlying object is usually an Array, ArrayCollection or Object, which I'm using as a kind of associative array. A Flex List is a visual component so I wouldn't use it in model code.

Comment: www.Flextras.com, you were right. The architecture was wrong. I was building syncing across the network into the events. When I moved that behaviour to explicit calls in my controllers and parameterised actions using the command pattern, I found that event suppression was no longer necessary and I could rip out huge chunks of unnecessary code.

Thanks for the heads-up.